# Custom Tags Archive - permalinks not working

Tags: customization, tags, archives

I need to create Custom tags archive like normal tags in post_type "post".

ex: i need this 
http://sitename.com/mtag/test
work like
http://sitename.com/tag/test

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_mtags_taxonomy' );
function create_mtags_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                           => 'More Tags',
        'singular_name'                  => 'More Tags',
        'menu_name'                      => 'More Tags',
    );
    register_taxonomy(
        'mtags',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'More Tags' ),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'show_tagcloud' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'mtag'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: At first glance, that should just work, as long as you've flushed your rewrite rules. You can do that by going into the settings and saving permalinks again.

Comment: No problem. I've pasted my comment into an answer. If you don't mind accepting it, that will show the question as answered and help keep the site tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, that should just work, as long as you've flushed your rewrite rules. You can do that by going into the settings and saving permalinks again.

Comment: Hey again,  i need to show the page title.

Comment: As in something like "More Tags: Test?" If you make a new question I'll add an answer.

Comment: Done!  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233074/how-to-get-title-to-custom-tags-page