# how to get title to custom tags page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development, pages, tags, title

how to get title to custom tags page ?
&
how to make if condition like to my taxonamy

```
if ( is_page() ) {
    the_title();
} elseif ( is_tag() ) { 
    single_tag_title();
}
```

tax:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_mtags_taxonomy' );
function create_mtags_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                           => 'More Tags',
        'singular_name'                  => 'More Tags',
        'menu_name'                      => 'More Tags',
    );
    register_taxonomy(
        'mtags',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'More Tags' ),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'show_tagcloud' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'mtag'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand your conditional to check for display of one of your terms, you can do this:

```
if ( is_page() ) {
    the_title();
} elseif ( is_tag() ) { 
    single_tag_title();
} elseif ( is_tax( 'mtags' ); ) { 
    single_term_title('More Tags: ');
}
```

However, if you use your theme's custom taxonomy template for this taxonomy, `taxonomy-mtags.php`, then you can just do something like:

```
<h1 class="page-title">
    <?php single_term_title('More Tags: '); ?>
</h1>
```